# Recover old jupyter notebooks

Tags: python, installation, pip, jupyter, file-recovery

I had to uninstall everything on my laptop and reinstall including python and jupyter. Now I dnt see any of my jupyter notebooks when I launch jupyter. I am having almost a heart attack!
How I can recover my codes in jupuyter?

some additional info: This was part of our company transition from legacy company to new company. We basically lost all installed programs as the results of this transition. I know, very stupid but I was not involved in making decisions!

Comment: The notebooks should be their own files that are not removed when the software is uninstalled. Try searching the whole computer for *.ipynb?

Comment: where usually they are saved? In program files where other notebook installers are?